# While выводит только первую итерацию в цикле

Tags: php, while

Есть тестовый код в учебных целях, крутится на xampp:

```
<html>
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        print <<<PROGRAM
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Program</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                print '<select name="people">;          
                while ($i < 10) {
                    print '<option>$i</option>';
                    $i++;
                }
                print '</select>';
            </body>
        </html>
        PROGRAM;
    ?>
</html>
```

В браузере выводится только первое значение 1. При просмотре исходного кода через браузер, он выглядит следующим образом:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=Zt4V-HcipvBh_pPEXdKYCgw-eJkqbsFRLfJfbsuQlArJ5UuV0TJO00-62gpawCtC" charset="UTF-8"></script><html>
    <head>
        <title>Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        print '<select name="people">;          
        while (1 < 10) {
            print '<option>1</option>';
            1++;
        }
        print '</select>';
    </body>
</html></html>
```

Где ошибка и почему это происходит ?

Comment: Чтобы цикл выполнился нужно, чтобы он быт в самом скрипте, а print выводит в результирующий файл, поэтому ваш цикл и не выполняется.

Comment: @becouse Это правильный ответ, может оформите полноценно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы цикл выполнился нужно, чтобы он был в самом скрипте, а print выводит в результирующий файл, поэтому ваш цикл и не выполняется.

Как правильно отмечают в комментариях, внутри HEREDOC код не выполняется, только подстановка переменных.

Вот, например так, можно переработать программу. Но вообще лучше взять учебник по PHP и поработать с ним.

```
$i = 1;
echo <<<PROGRAM
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Program</title>
            </head>
            <body>
PROGRAM;
                print '<select name="people">\n';          
                while ($i < 10) {
                    print '<option>$i</option>\n';
                    $i++;
                }
                print '</select>\n';

echo <<<PROGRAM
</body>
</html>
PROGRAM;
```

Comment: Что за дичь, какой апостроф? С какого там релиза вдруг HEREDOC стал парсить и выполнять код?

Comment: Но апостроф то пропущен.

Comment: И что - это решит проблему топикстартера?

Comment: Только Вы его не в то место воткнули - после закрывающего тега надо, а не перед ним

Comment: Странный ответ, вы же сами правильно написали в комментариях: что в html не парсится php а выводится как есть.

Comment: И @u_mulder правильно пишет: внутри HEREDOC не выполняется php-код, это и есть корневая причина того, что в html попадает невыполненный код. Если не сложно -- приведите пример кода, чтобы уж совсем наглядно переделать до работающего состояния.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за ответ!
Я и занимаюсь изучением по книжке, но в ней видимо ошибка в этом примере.
С вашим примером практически все заработало, за исключением того что в выпадающем списке не цифры 1, 2, 3, ...9, а 9 раз повторяется $i. Получается цикл работает, но значение не заполняется. Поправил вот так, заработало:

```
while ($i < 10) {
print <<<PROGRAM
print '<option>$i</option>';
PROGRAM;
$i++;
}
```

Большое спасибо что помогли!